# How can I get ByteBuddy to build a class implementation and initialise the member variables?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have been searching extensively without success, and can't find the answer in the examples.

Having a class with the following members:

```
public class Foo {
  public String name;
  public Long age;
}
```

I want to build a new implementation of this class that initialises the member variables by delegating to some initliaiser class.

```
Bar dynamicType = new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V8)
                .subclass(Foo)
                .initializer(new BarInit())
                .make()
                .load(Foo.class.getClassLoader(), WRAPPER)
                .getLoaded()
                .newInstance();
```

also created

```
public class BarInit implements LoadedTypeInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onLoad(Class<?> type) {
       Field[] fields = type.getDeclaredFields();
       // fields is empty?!
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAlive() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think I've gone code-blind. I need a hint.

So after some hints I moved on to

```
public class Foo {

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Foo(Bar qClass) {
        this();
    }

  public String name;
  public Long age;
}

FooBar dynamicType = new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V8)
        .subclass(Foo)
        .defineConstructor(PUBLIC)
                .withParameter(Bar.class, "initClass")
                .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE
                .andThen(MethodDelegation.to(new Interceptor())))
        .make()
        .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
        .getLoaded()
        .getDeclaredConstructor(Bar.class)
        .newInstance(new Bar());
```

results in `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call super (or default) method`

The interceptor has

```
public void intercept(@Origin Constructor m) {
    System.out.println("Intercepted: " + m.getName());
}
```

and now it 'works', although I'm still to figure out the initialisation part! And ultimately, the class `Foo` now has constructors I didn't want.

But - HOLD THE PRESS!

I experimented/read into the small hours and came up with:

```
    public class Foo {

        public Foo() {
        }

      public String name;
      public Long age;
    }

    FooBar dynamicType = new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V8)
            .subclass(Foo)
            .defineConstructor(PUBLIC)
                    .withParameter(Bar.class)
                    .intercept(MethodCall.(Foo.class.getDeclaredConstructor())
                    .andThen(MethodDelegation.to(new Interceptor())))
            .make()
            .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
            .getLoaded()
            .getConstructor(Bar.class)
            .newInstance(new Bar());


    public void intercept(Bar cls) {
        System.out.println("Intercepted: " + cls);
    }
```

What remains is to discover how to get a reference to the instance being constructed being made available to `intercept()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some 20 hours of trial-and-error based on reading 40+ different 'solutions' to similar - but ultimately different - problems, I arrived at the following, which seems to do what I intended.

```
public class Foo {
      public String name;
      public Long age;
    }

public class Bar {
      public String name() {
          return "Name";
      }
      public Long age() {
          return 21;
      }
    }

public class Demo {

    FooBar dynamicType = new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V8)
            .subclass(Foo)
            .defineConstructor(PUBLIC)
                    .withParameter(Bar.class)
                    .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(Foo.class.getDeclaredConstructor())
                    .andThen(MethodDelegation.to(this)))
            .make()
            .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
            .getLoaded()
            .getConstructor(Bar.class)
            .newInstance(new Bar());

    public void intercept(@This Object thiz, @Argument(0) Bar bar) {
        thiz.name = bar.name();
        thiz.age = bar.age();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps some other poor soul who has been burning the midnight oil.

Answer (score 1):

Your fields are instance fields defined by `Foo`. If you define an `LoadedTypeInitializer` it will initialize the subclass of `Foo` that does not declare the two fields in question. Therefore the array is empty. Also, the type initializer will not get you anywhere as it is used for initializing the type, not the instance.

You probably want to define a constructor and set the fields from there. Remember that any constructor needs to invoke a super constructor or another constructor of the same class first. (Have a look at `SuperMethodCall` for that.

Comment: Ok, I understand things a bit better now, but still having trouble on getting `intercept()` to work. Any examples seem to be for methods without parameters and not parameterised constructors.

Comment: SuperMethodCall expects a super method with identical signature. Have a look at MethodCall to invoke any other method.

Comment: Now I am *really* confused. Previous advice was to define constructor and use `SuperMethodCall`. Now that I know about it expecting the same signature as the intercepted constructor, I can handle that. But what if all I need is the subclass to call the default constructor of the base class and then initialise the class? 


`class Foobar extends Foo { public Foobar() { super(); //TODO init } }`

Comment: I've looked at `Advice.to()` as well to get inline code to work - but it seems I can get it to work for methods with `MethodCall.invoke()`, but not constructors.